# Removing and adding thousands separators for numbers in Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I'm testing UI against some calculation made in code in robot Framework.
My calculation result is like 12000 but on UI its 12,000
so I want to convert 12000 to that grouping like number 12,000 - to add a comma as thousands separator.

Comment: Is the result always 12000 or does it vary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an integer and want to convert it to string with thousands separators, the easiest way is to use [python's string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

```
${int variable}=    Set Variable    ${12000}
${string var}=      Evaluate     "{:,}".format($int_variable)
Should Be Equal As Strings   ${string var}    12,000
```

If you're using Robotframework version >= 3.1, there's the keyword [`Format String`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Format%20String) that does precisely that:

```
${int variable}=    Set Variable    ${12000}
${string var}=      Format String     {:,}    ${int_variable}
Should Be Equal As Strings   ${string var}    12,000
```

---

If you want to do the other way around - from "12,000" to get "12000" - drop the thousands separators, use the [`Remove String` keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Remove%20String):

```
${my string}=     Set Variable    12,000
${my string}=     Remove String    ${my string}    ,
Should Be Equal As Strings    ${my string}   12000
```

Comment: Do you know how to convert same with "." ? I have integer number lets say 1 and I want to convert it to 1.0. I tried Convert to number but not working.